# Google Maps SDK iOS - Calculate radius according zoom Level

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I need calculate radius to show markers on the map according camera zoom level. Right now I've got southWestCorner and my location that is center of my MapView. I need zoom out and calculate new radius when zoom changed.

Does anyone know how to get it from data I have?

My code is here:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!) {

        println("latitude: \(position.target.latitude) longtitude: \(position.target.longitude)")

        var visibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
        var cameraZoom = mapView.camera.zoom
        var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(region: visibleRegion)
        var southWestCorner = bounds.southWest

    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, I have found good answer for my question. Maybe it could be helpful to anyone else. according this [article](http://jslim.net/blog/2013/07/02/ios-get-the-radius-of-mkmapview/)

To get radius should use next example (all functions translated to swift):

```
// calculate radius
    func getCenterCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        var centerPoint = self.mapView.center
        var centerCoordinate = self.mapView.projection.coordinateForPoint(centerPoint)
        return centerCoordinate
    }

    func getTopCenterCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        // to get coordinate from CGPoint of your map
        var topCenterCoor = self.mapView.convertPoint(CGPointMake(self.mapView.frame.size.width / 2.0, 0), fromView: self.mapView)
        var point = self.mapView.projection.coordinateForPoint(topCenterCoor)
        return point
    }

    func getRadius() -> CLLocationDistance {

        var centerCoordinate = getCenterCoordinate()
        // init center location from center coordinate
        var centerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: centerCoordinate.latitude, longitude: centerCoordinate.longitude)
        var topCenterCoordinate = self.getTopCenterCoordinate()
        var topCenterLocation = CLLocation(latitude: topCenterCoordinate.latitude, longitude: topCenterCoordinate.longitude)

        var radius = CLLocationDistance(centerLocation.distanceFromLocation(topCenterLocation))

        return round(radius)
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Updated Antons anwser to Swift 3 and as an extension of `GMSMapView`

```
extension GMSMapView {
    func getCenterCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        let centerPoint = self.center
        let centerCoordinate = self.projection.coordinate(for: centerPoint)
        return centerCoordinate
    }

    func getTopCenterCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        // to get coordinate from CGPoint of your map
        let topCenterCoor = self.convert(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: 0), from: self)
        let point = self.projection.coordinate(for: topCenterCoor)
        return point
    }

    func getRadius() -> CLLocationDistance {
        let centerCoordinate = getCenterCoordinate()
        let centerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: centerCoordinate.latitude, longitude: centerCoordinate.longitude)
        let topCenterCoordinate = self.getTopCenterCoordinate()
        let topCenterLocation = CLLocation(latitude: topCenterCoordinate.latitude, longitude: topCenterCoordinate.longitude)
        let radius = CLLocationDistance(centerLocation.distance(from: topCenterLocation))
        return round(radius)
    }
}
```

Calling `self.map.getRadius()` would return the radius

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `southWest`, you should use the `near/far`+`Left/Right`. Refer to the [GMSVisibleRegion Struct Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/struct_g_m_s_visible_region). The reason being that southWest does not cover the 3D maps situations.

After you get the farRight, farLeft, nearRight, and nearLeft, you can calculate the distance between the two mid-points of the two horizontal edge, as well as the distance for vertical edge. Then you pick the smaller value, which should be your radius.

Comment: Thank you, do you have some example or formula?

Comment: I think Google Maps has a function to calculate distance between two points. Also since lat/lng are in degree and the mid points would simply be `[ (FL.lat+NL.lat)/2, (FL.lng + NL.lng)/2 ]`, and `[ (FR.lat+NR.lat)/2, (FR.lng + NR.lng)/2 ]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapView.projection.visibleRegion()` to find the corner coordinates on the visible screen.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    
    // Find the coordinates
    let visibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
    let farLeftLocation = CLLocation(latitude: visibleRegion.farLeft.latitude, longitude: visibleRegion.farLeft.longitude)
    let centerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: position.target.latitude, longitude: position.target.longitude)

    // Calculate the distance as radius.
    // The distance result from CLLocation is in meters, so we divide it by 1000 to get the value in kilometers
    let radiusKM = centerLocation.distance(from: farLeftLocation) / 1000.0

    // Do something with the radius...

}
```